# Placing Osmdroid Mapview inside Dialog

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

This doesn't seem to work. I ran into a similar issue in the google group from way back (sept. 2011) which describes it pretty well:

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Create own DialogPreference
2. override onCreateDialogView
3. return a MapView instance

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Expected: MapView inside Dialog.
Instead: Just OK/Cancel Buttons

But there was no answer.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks